# Debugging of for loop

Tags: java

I have this piece of code used to create `route` object. I check that `route` capacity `cap` does not exceed `MAX_CAPACITY`.

```
    java.util.Collections.shuffle(randomizedLocations, new Random(111));
    List<Integer> route = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int cap = 0; int k=0;
    while ((cap+locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight()) <= MAX_CAPACITY)
    {
        route.add(randomizedLocations.get(k));
        cap += locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight();
        k++;
        if (k>=locations.size())
            break;
    }
```

Afterwards I check the final result as follows and found out that `cap` exceeds `MAX_CAPACITY`:

```
    cap=0;
    for(int j=0; j < route.size(); j++)
        cap += locations.get(route.get(j)).getWeight();
```

Where is the error??

Comment: you compared (cap+....) to MAX_CAPACITY not just cap

Comment: which is correct. If you would compare just cap, the error would be obvious. For me the code looks correct.

Comment: @lex82: For me too. Then I misunderstand 1) downvoting and 2) the reason of this error.

Comment: Well, downvoting is probably for just showing a small portion of your code and asking for the error. You could provide more detail on the first part, e.g., where does randomizedLocations come from?

Comment: is randomizedLocations.get(k) returning random value?

Comment: @lex82: please see the update.

Comment: Assuming `route` isn't modified after the loop but before the check then I can't see an issue. I'd do some refactoring to make it easier to read - might help spot the issue. e.g. Don't call `randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight()` twice - store it's return and use that inside the loop. IF that is non deterministic then your problem is gone. You could probably also store the result of `randomizedLocations.get(k)` too.

Comment: I assume `getWeight()` returns an int? We don't have to consider floating point rounding at all?

Comment: @John3136: Hmm, it returns double value.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos I'd be pretty confident that you've got some rounding issues. Why not make `cap` and `MAX_CAPACITY`  `double` since that seems to be what they are meant to be...?

Comment: @John3136: Thanks, I haven't noticed it. But anyway the reason was different. I followed your advise and stored `locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight()` to not call it twice.

Comment: @John3136 It seems you are right, but I still can't see how it happens. It seems for me that the rounding errors should be the same when summing up in the check. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Since `getWeight()` returns a `double` (as revealed in comments), when it is converted to an `int`, rounding is applied which may cause some unexpected behavior "close to the edges" (so 1.0 is < 2.0, but 2.000000001 may compare as <= 2.0 depending on how the float is stored. There are plenty of questions/answers about this, just look one up).

Comment: I'm still not convinced. Klausos klausos commented on his own answer that the double was not the problem. And the ways the sum is calculated I would expect exactly the same rounding errors.

Comment: I'm lost. The original code in the question did "check, add, k++", so that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments of `John3136`, I came to the solution of a problem:

```
        double cap = 0;  
        int k=0; 
        double nc = locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight();
        while ((cap+nc) <= SAConstants.MAX_CAPACITY && k<locations.size())
        {
            route.add(randomizedLocations.get(k));
            cap += nc;
            k++;
            if (k>=locations.size())
                break;
            nc=locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight();
        }
```

Comment: So how did you solve it? Was it the double or not calling randomizedLocations.get() twice?

Comment: No, that was not an issue with double in my particular case. That was not calling `randomizedLocations.get(k)` twice. Probably the reason was that I did `k++` inside the loop and then used this `k` in `((cap+locations.get(randomizedLocations.get(k)).getWeight())`

Comment: Your use of `k` in the original code was fine - you used the same k for the check and add, and then incremented it. No problem with that.